# Ordered Questions from a list of objects

Tags: spring-boot, random

I have a list of objects (Question objects).I need specific number of objects in a random order.For example I have 100 objects and I need 50 of them but in a random order.How to achieve it using Spring Boot?

Comment: just by trying to do it before and then asking for help...

Comment: Shuffle the list, then select the first 50.

Answer (score 1):

If your questions are in questionsList and you are using Java 8:

```
 Collections.shuffle(questionsList);
 questionsList.stream().limit(50).collect(Collectors.toList());
```